# Array in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column 'sample_column' which is an array.

Can anyone tell me how can I select data based on 'sample_column' in postgresql?

Example of data in sample_column: ["one","two","three"]

I want to get all data if sample_column has value "three"

Here is what I have done:

```
Select * from sample_table where sample_column contains 'three'
```

I am getting ERROR.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What was the error? You can try `SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE sample_column LIKE '%three%'`

Comment: "syntax error at or near contains"

Comment: @Sinto now getting "operator does not exist"

Comment: Can you add a sample screenshot of column with data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have table as:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
    sample_column text[]
);
```

and you have insert data as:

```
insert into table_name(sample_column) values (array['one','two','three']);
insert into table_name(sample_column) values (array['yes','no']);
insert into table_name(sample_column) values (array['red','white','blue']);
```

now you want to find recored based on the array element:

```
select * from table_name where 'three' = ANY(sample_column);
```

I hope it helps.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/752d9/2)

Comment: Hope your code may help. I was wrong about column type. I have added a demo, please & verify that.